# Firebase Realtime database correct reference is returning null

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I was working on a project, While working on a real-time database the references are correctly configured but retuning null.

```
DatabaseReference reference = database.getReference(map.get(SessionManager.KEY_CARID)+"/Alert/status");
        //DatabaseReference reference = database.getReference(map.get(SessionManager.KEY_CARID)).child("Alert").child("status");
        reference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
              if (snapshot.getValue().toString().equalsIgnoreCase("1")) {
```

In this if statement the function tostring() is not working as its giving null pointer exception. The database structure is as followed.

[image]

Comment: Are you sure the references are configured correctly?  We can't see what's in `map.get(SessionManager.KEY_CARID)`, and if it matches what you show in your database.  Try hard coding a value first.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
DatabaseReference reference = database.getReference("User").child(map.get(SessionManager.KEY_CARID)).child("Alert").child("status");
```

You need to reference the node `User`